# Implementing high-precision addition with arrays

Tags: arrays, c

When I choose the example`/ 100000000 999` or `/ 10000 99` , there is no output about my codes, but when I choose the example `/ 1000 99`, the output of this tample is correct `10`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1000
int an1[MAX_LEN+10], an2[MAX_LEN+10];
char szLine1[MAX_LEN+10], szLine2[MAX_LEN+10];

void mul(int a[], int an, int b[], int bn, int fa, int fb);
void plus(int an1[], int an2[]);
void div(int an1[], int nlen1, int an2[], int nlen2, int fa, int fb);
void sub(int an1[], int nLen1, int an2[], int nLen2);
int compare_num(int an1[], int nLen1, int an2[], int nLen2);

int main(){
    char op = getchar(); getchar();
    int i = 0, j = 0, nLen1 = 0, nLen2 = 0; 
    memset(an1, 0, sizeof(an1)); memset(an2, 0, sizeof(an2));

    int fa = 1, fb = 1;
    scanf("%s", szLine1); nLen1 = strlen(szLine1);
    scanf("%s", szLine2); nLen2 = strlen(szLine2);
    if(szLine1[0] == '-') fa = -1; if(szLine2[0] == '-') fb = -1;
    if(fa == -1){
        for(i = nLen1-1; i >= 1; i--){
        an1[j++] = szLine1[i] - '0';
        }}else{
        for(i = nLen1-1; i >= 0; i--){
        an1[j++] = szLine1[i] - '0';
        }}
    if(fb == -1){
        for(i = nLen1-1; i >= 1; i--){
        an2[j++] = szLine2[i] - '0';
        }}else{
        for(i = nLen2-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--){
        an2[j++] = szLine2[i] - '0';
        }
    }
    //以上两个循环将szline中的输入的数组倒置放入an数组中
    switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
        plus(an1, an2);
        break;
    case '-':
        sub(an1, nLen1, an2, nLen2);
        break;
    case '*':
        mul(an1, nLen1, an2, nLen2, fa, fb);
        break;
    case '/':
        div(an1, nLen1, an2, nLen2, fa, fb);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
int compare_num(int an1[], int nLen1, int an2[], int nLen2){
    int count = 0;
    if(nLen1 > nLen2) return 1;
    else if(nLen1 < nLen2) return -1;
    else if(nLen1 == nLen2){
        for(int i = nLen1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(an1[i] > an2[i]) return 1;
            else if(an1[i] < an2[i]) return -1;
            else if(an1[i] == an2[i]){
                count++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(count == nLen1) return 0;
    }
}

void div(int an1[], int nlen1, int an2[], int nlen2, int fa, int fb){
    int count = 0;
    int sign = compare_num(an1, nlen1, an2, nlen2);
    if(sign == 1){

        while(compare_num(an1, nlen1, an2, nlen2) == 1 || compare_num(an1, nlen1, an2, nlen2) == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i <= nlen2; i++){
            if(an2[i] > an1[i]){
                an1[i] = an1[i]+10-an2[i];
                an1[i+1]--;
            }else{
                an1[i] = an1[i] - an2[i];}}
            if(an1[nlen1-1] == 0) nlen1--;
            count++;
            if(nlen1 < nlen2) break;
        }
        if(fa * fb < 0) printf("-");
        printf("%d", count);
    }else{
        printf("0");
    }
}
```

I have tried samples, such as `/ 30 1`(output is `29`, of course fault), and `/ 1000000000 99`(fault), but how ever when I choose `/ 2300 200` to test, output is correct, why cause that?The reason I didn't get any output, is it because of a timeout, or is there another reason?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your `compare_num` function is wrong.
Specifically, the starting value `int i = nLen1` is wrong. It should start with `nLen-1` like you did in the `main` function.

Secondly, your `div` function is wrong.

The condition `sign == 1` should be `sign != -1`. Otherwise, your program will fail with cases like `/ 100 100` (The answer should be `1`, but `0` is printed).

Also, you should use `i < nlen1` as the loop condition instead of `i <= nlen2` to update all of the dividend.
Then, instead of referencing `an2[i]` directly, you should conditionally read `an2` like `int value2 = i < nlen2 ? an2[i] : 0;` not to read uninitialized or out-of-range area of `an2`. (In this specific code, directly reading `an2[i]` is not harmful because `an2` is a global variable and the default value of elements is `0`)

Comment: Having done your advice, there is still no outcome, why cause this? Is my core code wrong(such as the `div` function)?